# Is there any reason not to keep PHP unit tests with the class under test?

Tags: php, unit-testing

The standard practice with PHP unit testing in frameworks such as PHPUnit and PHPSpec seems to be to keep the test cases in a separate directory away from the classes under test, e.g:

```
FoobarApp
├── Models
│   ├── SomeModel
├── Tests
│   ├── SomeModelTest
```

Personally I find it clearer and more helpful to put each test next to the class it is testing in the same directory like this:

```
FoobarApp
├── Models
│   ├── SomeModel
│   └── SomeModelTest
```

My question is: is there any reason not to use this alternative placement? Is this just a developer preference issue?

Comment: What if you want to deploy (meaning you don't want test classes). Wouldn't it be easier to deploy without the directory /Tests instead of having to find out what to pick spread out through different directories? Also having test classes mixed with "normal" classes makes a unmaintainable mess in a decent sized project imo

Comment: @PeeHaa I did consider that the test classes would also be deployed in most deployment processes, but I don't see that that's necessarily a problem? I don't agree with the "unmaintainable mess" point at all, do you have anything to substantiate that? On the contrary, keeping the tests with the class under test makes them much easier to develop and maintain in my view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this just a developer preference issue?

Basically, yes.

It started out as a preference and is quite common in OOP languages, e.g. also in Java they're usually separated.

Others deemed there are more benefits having these tests separate:

- don't clutter your implementation tree
- having a single test class for a single implementation class it just common, but no rule. If it makes sense, it might be appropriate to have multiple test classes for your implementation class. Now take this into account if all of them are also in your `src/` tree.
- clean separate for deployment. No one needs test cases in production; having them in a separate directory makes it dumb-easy to exclude them.
- easier separation when searching through the code base. Most of the time I'm not interesting searching the tests

You can either accept what most developers are accustomed to or roll your own thing, no ones is stopping or forcing you. But once you work with others (teams @ work, OSS) you'll find that most are separating them.

No one will care in your private project, but if you OSS your thing and expect collaboration, you want to ease it for anyone by just applying the common conventions.

### For example:

I'm not a fan of PSR-2:

- separate `{` on classes/methods? Nay
- 4 spaces? I prefer 2.

However you dislike a standard: there are benefits when collaborating, **thinking as a team**. Thus I switched to PSR-2 in all of my projects although I personally dislike it.

There's no place for personal ego when collaborating with others. That's not to say you've to submit to everything. You decide on your own how well you play as part of a bigger picture ;-)

Comment: This is a decent and the correct answer however considering the fact that you admit to use 2 spaces I just cannot upvote it. That's just horrible :P

Comment: I prefer a right margin of 80 chars and it just gets really hard with 4 spaces. I also love working with vertical splits and therefore having 80 to 100 chars helps getting them on screen without enough room.